# Flash video player that supports setting cookies?

Tags: javascript, .net, flash, web

I've tried JWPlayer from my app (C#). It works well, but I can't seem to find cookie support. I need to send a cookie or else the server will return 403 Forbidden. Is there any commercial flash player with cookie support (or I'm missing something in JWPlayer's doc)

Comment: Why do you want cookie support?

Comment: Because the links are unreachable without this cookie.

Comment: Can't you set the cookie inside the C# app?

Comment: The point was to set it from the player side, so it can play the file. Not to download it from the c# using the cookie and then play it in the flash player.

Comment: Why can't you set the cookie using javascript instead of using flash player? The result would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could set and get the cookie via C# and pass it to your player with a flashvar.

Or call a js function from the flash movie that will set the cookie.

Comment: Isn't that only if the video player supports setting cookies?

Comment: No you can just set the cookie the way you want outside of Flash and pass it to Flash with flashvars or js.

I don't think ActionScript has any kind of cookie handling.